# Custom API controller returns no records

Tags: linq, azure, asp.net-apicontroller

I need to return the results from a sql query to my mobile app.

I have a database on azure and a mobile service.

I have added a new custom API controller to my service, but I can't get any records back.  I've been reading and reading and still do not understand what I am missing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Net;    
using System.Net.Http;    
using System.Web.Http;    
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;    
using mytestService.Models;    
using mytestService.DataObjects;    
using System.Data.Common;    
using System.Data.SqlClient;    
using System.Data;    
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
namespace mytestService.Controllers    
{    
    public class SelectMapMarkersController : ApiController     
    {    
        public ApiServices Services { get; set; }    
        public class MapMarkers
        {
            public string MerchantName { get; set; }
            public double MerchantLongitude { get; set; }
            public double MerchantLatitude { get; set; }
            public string MerchantMiniURL { get; set; }
            public string Deal { get; set; }
            public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
        }   

        // GET api/SelectMapMarkers
        public List<MapMarkers> Get() 
        {
             using (mytestContext context = new mytestContext())
            {
                // Get the database from the context.
                var database = context.Database;
                 string sql = "select MerchantName, MerchantLongitude, MerchantLatitude, MerchantMiniUrl, Deal, CategoryDescription from mytest.tblMerchants m inner join mytest.tblMerchantDeals d on d.merchantId = m.merchantid inner join mytest.tblMerchantCategories mc on mc.merchantid = m.merchantid inner join mytest.tblCategories c on c.categoryid = mc.categoryid where m.MerchantActive = 1 and (d.dealstartdate <= getdate() and d.dealenddate >= getdate()) ";

                List<MapMarkers> result = database.SqlQuery<MapMarkers>(sql).ToList<MapMarkers>();
                return result;

            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged up until 'return result;'?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try...

Head over the database using SSMS and execute the t-sql line manually and see what the results are.